# How to change color of TEdit when focused

Tags: background-color, firemonkey, onfocus

It's probably easy question, bu I can't find an answer.

I want to change background color of TEdit component when I click on it (on Focus), and the background should back to previous color when I click somewhere else.

P.S. I use a Firemonkey and it's multiplatform app, so I need to use a style.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and best) - place TRectangle without Stroke into Tedit, set its Align to Client and change its Fill color in Object Inspector.

Hard way: 
Tedit is using bitmap from styles. You can see your current style for Tedit - place StyleBook, Load your style from file, find 'editstyle' object.
You can create a new style for Tedit (copy 'editstyle' in your current style, and name it like editstyle1, select background > Source Link in Object Inspector - select part on global style bitmap with your color, then you can change to new style like Edit1.StyleLookup := 'editstyle1';
Also use a useful forum: http://fire-monkey.ru with Google Translate.

Comment: The easiest way (and best) - place TRectangle without Stroke into Tedit, set its Align to Client and change its Fill color in Object Inspector.

but this way will change the color all the time and not only when there is focus.

Comment: You would have to do this in the OnEnter and OnExit event handlers... for every control you want this behaviour for. Or subclass the TEdit and define your own custom edit control that does this. But IMHO styles are the right way to go.

Comment: styles are the right way to go
But how to change color when I click on tedit box?
Can you show me?